# Writing new lines to a text file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text, newline

I'm creating an error log file. This is my current code:

```
Add-Content -path $logpath $((get-date).tostring() + " Error " + $keyPath `
   + $value + " key " + $key +" expected: " + $policyValue `
   + "`n local value is: " +$localValue
```

When I `Get-Content` on the log file, it displays correctly, with the new line before "local value."

However, when I open the log file in Notepad, it displays everything on a single line. How can I cause it to insert a new line into the text file as well?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`` `n `` is a line feed character. Notepad ([prior to Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/)) expects linebreaks to be encoded as `` `r`n `` (carriage return + line feed, CR-LF). Open the file in some useful editor ([SciTE](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html), [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [UltraEdit-32](https://www.ultraedit.com/), [Vim](https://www.vim.org/), ...) and convert the linebreaks to CR-LF. Or use PowerShell:

```
(Get-Content $logpath | Out-String) -replace "`n", "`r`n" | Out-File $logpath
```

Comment: If I changed the code to include the carraige return before the linefeed, ould notepad show the file correctly?

Comment: If you create the file anew: yes, it should show a newly created file correctly then.

Comment: I'm using PowerShell v4 (`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`) and using Both ```r`n creates two blank lines when using `r`n` | Out-File -Encode Ascii`  so I switched to only ```r` which correctly creates a single line space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the job well. Cheers.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [Environment class's static NewLine property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) to get the proper newline:

```
$errorMsg =  "{0} Error {1}{2} key {3} expected: {4}{5} local value is: {6}" -f `
               (Get-Date),$keyPath,$value,$key,$policyValue,([Environment]::NewLine),$localValue
Add-Content -Path $logpath $errorMsg
```

Comment: this is what i ended up using

Answer (score 19):

It's also possible to assign newline and carriage return to variables and then append them to texts inside PowerShell scripts:

```
$OFS = "`r`n"
$msg = "This is First Line" + $OFS + "This is Second Line" + $OFS
Write-Host $msg
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this;

```
Add-Content -path $logpath @"
$((get-date).tostring()) Error $keyPath $value
key $key expected: $policyValue
local value is:  $localValue
"@
```

Comment: The @ symbol changes how the text inside of the "'s are read. With the @'s the text is read 'as is'. Which means no additional processing is done to the text, and the newlines characters are included too.

Answer (score 2):

Values were not working for me when using Pipe command.
I Created an additional Add-Content with -Value of nothing ""
followed by the original Get | Add that I was trying to use.

```
$newfile = "C:\FilePath\Newfile.txt" 
$oldfile = "C:\FilePath\Oldfile.txt"

Add-Content -Path "$newfile" -value ""
Get-Content -Path "$oldfile | Add-Content -Path "$newfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Line-1$([Environment]::NewLine)`"Line-2`"$([Environment]::NewLine)Line-3"| out-File c:\Temp\abc.txt
```

[image]

[image]